# Reading and manipulating JSON elements on Python

Tags: python, json, list

I'm a python newbie and I need to read and manipulate elements from a json file, but I keep getting errors and I have no idea how to move forward. This is my code:

```
import json 
with open('file.txt', 'r') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
```

An example of the dataset:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'a',
        'city': 'Paris'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'b',
        'city': 'Mons'
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'c.',
        'city': 'Leuven'
    }
]
```

When I try to get only `id` or `name`, I get this error:

```
city = d['city']
```

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()
>
> ----> 1 city = d['city']
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Then I tried this:

```
city = d[:]['city']
```

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()
>   ----> 1 city = d[:]['city']
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How about `city = d[0]['city']`? Try looping instead

Comment: It is a list so as Arvind pointed out you should try putting the list index before the dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

You more likely don't want to know the array index of the element you are looking for.

With some pythonic flavor, you can create [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
arr = [(dict['id'], dict['city']) for dict in d]
```

The output would be

```
[(1, 'Paris'),
(2, 'Mons'),
(3, 'Leuven')]
```

Then, you have the possibility to get only specific items in your tuples if needed.

Ex:

```
arr = [(dict['id'], dict['city']) for dict in d if 's' in dict['city']]
```

which would return `id` and `name` for every entry that contain 's' in the city property.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop to go through each object

```
final=[]
for obj in d:
    final.append(obj['city'])
```

Or you can try using this

```
final = [obj['city'] for obj in d]
```

Or if you only need the first value then

```
print(d[0]['city'])
```

Output

> 'Paris'

Since your data is a list of dictionaries, you'll have to use the index value to get the data in the dictionary

Comment: Hari, thank you so much for your answer. One more thing, how can I save this output to another list? Again, thanks for your time and patience :)

Comment: I've added the code for appending the city to a list

Comment: Thanks Hari, I tried that before and I thought I wrote something wrong. I'm still getting the same error. I really don't get it :(
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: I've added another way to get a list of values. Please try that

Comment: I get an empty list as the output `[]`. Is there a way to get the list as strings?

Comment: You can `" ".join(listname)` to convert the list to a single string.Btw I am getting the following output when i am running the above code `['Paris', 'Mons', 'Leuven']`

Comment: Thank you very much, Hari :)

Answer (score 0):

As this is a dictionary within a list you must provide a list index before calling value by the key. This should work:

```
dict = d[0]
city = dict['city']
```

Or you can simply use:

```
city = d[0]['city']
```